# Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015 Team and Area permissions

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I have so far been unable to configure permissions correctly on TFS and was wondering if anyone could assist.

We've gone for the "One Big Project" approach, and have a TFS 2015 area structure as follows:

```
-- All IT Work
  -- Team 1
    -- Project X
    -- Project Y
  -- Team 2
    -- Project Z
  -- Team 3
```

When a manager visits the TFS backlog, they will want to see all the work in all of these areas (i.e. the All IT Work area, and all subareas). If they create a work item, it should be created in the All IT work Area
When a member of Team 1 visits the backlog, they should only be able to see the work in the Team 1 area and its subareas, and anything they create should go into the Team 1 area.  When a member of Team 2 visits the backlog, they should only see Team 2, and so on.

I thought it would be fairly simple to set the permissions for this.  I have an All IT Work team which contains only the managers.  On the TFS area screen, I have set this team to have All IT Work as its default area, and have checked all the subareas.  This part seems to work, so when a member of the All IT Work team browses to the backlog, they can see all the work in the top level and all sub areas.

I have created a Team 1 team which contains only the members of Team 1.  On the TFS area screen, I have set this team to have Team 1 as its default area, and have also included all subareas of Team 1.  According to this screen, this team doesn't have access to the All IT Work level, nor can it seem Team 2 or Team 3. The screen states **"Select the areas your team owns. Selected areas will determine what shows up on your team's backlog and what work items your team is responsible for."**

However, when I visit the backlog as a member of Team 1, I can still see All IT Work and all its subareas.

Can anyone advise what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are merely configuring the items that is visible on the backlog under the team in TFS. By the sounds of it they still have access to everything.

What you still need to do is [set the security](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/modify-areas-iterations#set-permissions-to-restrict-access-to-work-items) under the Area paths. I found that you remove all access on the root and then only allow users / groups areas to areas by setting the node's security.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this in a console application using TFS' API?